# Data is not entered into data base..?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

am trying to make a register form for my users using php, json and jquery request i think php code gose fine but i think problem is with jquery function..i am new to this all can u guys help me out..pardon me if am wrong and feel free to advice.

```
    **php code goes here:**

            <!--register.php-->
       <?php



require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
   $db = new DB_Functions();

    // json response array
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);
    if (isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['mobile'])) {
        var_dump('here');
        // receiving the post params
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

        // check if user is already existed with the same email
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user already existed
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // create a new user
            $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
                $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
                $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (fname, lname, email, password or mobile) is missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

hear gose the DB_Functions.php code...!

```
        <?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
         $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password, mobile) 
          VALUES('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$mobile."')";
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
       if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
```

And here goes the **front end** part for **data insertion..**

```
           <html>
        <head>
           <title>jQuery Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#submit").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                url: "localhost/web_login_api/register.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    fname: $("#fname").val(),
                    lname: $("#lname").val(),
                    email: $("#email").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val(),
                    mobile: $("#mobile").val()
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (jsonStr) {
                    $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
                }
            });

        }); 

        });
         </script>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div id = "result"></div>
        <!--html body-->
        <form name = "register" action = "#" id = "register" method = "POST">
            <label>First name:</label>
            <input type = text name = "fname" id = "fname">
            <label>Last name:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lname" id = "lname">
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            <input type = "email" name = "email" id = "email">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">
            <label>Mobile no:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "mobile" id = "mobile">
             <input type="button" value="Insert" name="submit" id="submit" href = "#">
            </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Does your value pass through php if(isset... ) ..?? I tired var_dumping inside isset.. It passes... But what i found was a bracket problem in if(isset..)...

Comment: can u plzz edit ma code and send..wer ive gone wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this now.. Edited..

In **DB_Functions.php** File

```
<?php

 class DB_Functions {
    private $db;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
     require_once 'config.php';
     try {
        $hostname = DB_HOST ;
        $dbname   = DB_DATABASE;
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile) {  
        try {
            $hash = md5($password);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO db_name(fname, lname, email, password, mobile) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$hash', $mobile)";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);

            if ($result) {
                // get user details
                $id = $this->db->lastInsertId(); //last inserted id
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE email = $email";
                $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                $no_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
                // returns confirmation message if completed
                if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                    return "existsandcompleted";
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = 'Error accessing database: ' . $e->getMessage();

        }

    }
}

?>
```

In main file

```
<?php
   require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
   $db = new DB_Functions();

    // json response array
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);
    if (isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['mobile'])) {

        // receiving the post params
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

         // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);

        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
            $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
            $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (fname, lname, email, password or mobile) is missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

This totally works.. If this not works then you have syntax errors somewhere ... Also, if you have int datatype to number field then dont make string.. Hope this works. !! Cheers !

Comment: EN now please check the DB_Functions.php code is it correct..??

Comment: Mistake in query .. Try this --> $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, fname, lname, email, encrypted_password, mobile, created_at) VALUES( '.$uuid.', '".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$email."', '".$encrypted_password."', '".$mobile."', NOW())");

Comment: hey..buddy i have corrected code as u said..!! but sadly its not getting inserted in to data base...is it the correct code.. plz check it out -thanks

Comment: its giving Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_login_api\DB_Functions.php on line 28

Comment: their is an error in DB_Function.php....plzz can u spot out it..m unable to resolve it

Comment: Thanks bud...u helped me lot!!

Comment: but..wats tat return"exitsandcomplited"

Comment: It simply returned that because the email address already exists in database..Are you learning PHP? refer w3schools and php.net for details..

Answer (score 0):

The values which your passing from the HTML code does not have password field in it and in your php you are trying to read password value. Either remove password field from your php or add password field in your HTML for desired output.

-Thanks

Comment: Are u saying in jquery part i must include password as  id..??

Comment: Yes you have to include password in the jquery part.

Comment: Variable names are also not a match, in HTML we are passing 'firstName' and in PHP we are searching for 'fname'. Make sure variables are same in both the files.

Comment: sorry to say..none worked out.. did u test the code..??

Comment: no..error message on click nothing happens ..page stays static

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with your jQuery,

Some helpful tips when debugging ajax is to use firebug or chromes network pane to insure the correct post variables are being sent and your not returning errors on your server side script.

---

**Potential Problem**

I do see an issue with your return type. If your returning JSON from your
 "register.php"

This can create problems.
Easy solution, set your content type header to JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

*Note this *MUST* be done before anything is echo'd or printed.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

---

**Suggestion**

- Bind event to the submit handler
- Construct object outside of the ajax method
- Run frontend validation
- Use a $.post wrapper

---

```
<form id="register" method="post" action="#">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        //ajax on form submit
        $("#register").submit(function (event) {
            //prevent default page reload
            event.preventDefault();
            //create post object
            var postUserRegistrationData = {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            };

            //for debugging dump it before sending
            console.log(postUserRegistrationData);

            //validate it (should be abstracted)
            if(!!postUserRegistrationData.name && !!postUserRegistrationData.password) {
                //post to the server
                $.post( "backend.php", postUserRegistrationData, function(data){
                    console.log("The reply:"+data);
                });
            } else {
                //throw if not valid
                alert("Validation Trigger");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You could have problems in the backend that are rooted much deeper. I'd suggest try returning (from the register script) echo json_encode($_POST); and viewing that in the console to insure your posting correctly.